# UI design for Django (making APIs or not)

Tags: django, django-templates

My UI designer is making me a rich html and java script front-end which is supposed to work with my Django server. I have provided him a bunch of APIs to get different elements from the server. (i.e. an api to load the images, another api to load some text, another api to load bigger size image when somebody clicked on a small one, etc.) The problem with this is that every time a user visits the page, I will be getting some number of requests.

On the other hand, I could have used django template tagging to render the page once with all the elements needed. however,

I was wondering if there is a clear benefit in one of these options?

Comment: Getting requests isn't what's the problem it's HOW you make the requests that's the big question. Smart use of AJAX and knowing when to load and _what_ to load is the big question. Also, try not to make any pre-optimizations until you've launched because it'll be hard to predict how it will perform.

Answer (score 0):

As @limelights said, try not to optimise too early. Because you don't really know what will be your bottleneck.

And when you'll have problems, the first thing to check is your queries to the database. Do you use selectect_related() and are your indexes optimal for your requests. This include the queries that javascript make via django (Try to load all the child node needed in one or two requests, as select_related() do).

After that the next optimisation should probably be cache. Here's the doc about the [django's cache framwork](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/cache/).

After that there's adanced optimisation with database denormalization, apache or nginx optimisation, mysql or postgresql settings optimisation, load balancing and etc... Those optimizationg should be done because you have a problem of popularity, not just for a few users.